# Vim syntax pattern to highlight python keyword argument

Tags: syntax-highlighting, regular-expression, filetype-python

I'm struggling with learning vim regexps (I don't know any other regexp very well either), so the main problem is to define regexp that would match

```
some_function_call(simple_value, keyword=value)
```

keyword in this example.

So it should match a word if it's inside parens and have equal sign after it.

The next problem is how to define syntax files in vim. I would appreciate help with that, but It shouldn't be that hard to learn, so I can do that on my own probably.

EDIT based on the answer I've maid my own syntax script for python. Feel free to try it.
[enter link description here](https://github.com/purpleP/python-syntax)

Comment: There is an open issue on Github for keyword highlighting to be included in the most up-to-date Python syntax file I am aware of: https://github.com/hdima/python-syntax/issues/44 You might want to check there later. If you figure out how to do it, please let the people there know (or message me so I can create a pull request) for this feature to be available for everyone.

Comment: Yeah, I'm the one who have opened it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With these settings:

```
syn region FCall start='[[:alpha:]_]\i*\s*(' end=')' contains=FCall,FCallKeyword
syn match FCallKeyword /\i*\ze\s*=[^=]/ contained
hi FCallKeyword ctermfg=yellow
```

I get:

[image]

Here:

1. I define a [syntax region](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#%3Asyn-region) within which keyword arguments can be found, which would be the function call. The `contains` option lets me nest function calls.
2. Within that region, I match any string made of valid identifier characters (`\i*`) followed by `=`, but not `==`, so that equality tests are not matched.

By using regions, I get to nest the matches as much as I need, which would have be very complicated (impossible?) if I'd gone for just a `match` with regular expressions.

I believe the regular expressions used for matching the function call and the keyword can be refined, but considering [what's valid in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19482755/2072269), that's not a task I'm willing to take on.

Optionally, I think you can use this to highlight function calls, using a [`matchgroup`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#%3Asyn-matchgroup):

```
syn region FCall matchgroup=FName start='[[:alpha:]_]\i*\s*(' end=')' contains=FCall,FCallKeyword
syn match FCallKeyword /\i*\ze\s*=[^=]/ contained
hi FCallKeyword ctermfg=yellow
hi FName ctermfg=blue
```

[image]

Comment: I probably should create another question, but do you have ideas about how to highlight only builtin functions?

Comment: @user1685095 Builtin functions are listed out in the `pythonBuiltin` syntax group in the default `syntax/python.vim`. However, it doesn't distinguish between functions and builtin variables (`True`, `False` and `None` are also in `pythonBuiltin`). You could probably copy the definitions for your use.

Comment: Well, I've used more refined syntax then vim default like hdima/python and vim-polyglot. They all define builtin functions like a keyword which have important consequence. Not only builtin functions are highlighted, but just variable with same names and functions in other modules with the same name are highlighted.
Like ```query(...).***filter***()``` filter is highlighted while it doesn't have anything to do with builtin filter functions.

Comment: @user1685095 the default `syntax.vim` does make them keywords. See https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/syntax/python.vim#L184

Comment: Yeah, I know. That's the problem. They are not keywords.

Comment: @user1685095 Odd. I don't have additional `syntax/python.vim` files (only the default, and I don't see the behaviour you do: http://i.stack.imgur.com/LgF6F.png, and I agree with the keyword definition - that's the closest fit, and I don't think keywords are matched in cases like `nonkeyword.keyword`. As for variables, note that these builtins *are* variables, they're variables containing function objects, and can be assigned to just like any other variables. Nothing prevents you from doing `sorted = filter` and then using `sorted` like `filter`.

Comment: Oh, I probably should try to base my own syntax on default vim syntax. Thanks. As for builtins as variables - then you should really only highlight them if it's not user defined variables, which probably impossible in vim. So I think the better of two evils is the one where you highlight them only when you use them as functions and not as variables.

Answer (score 8):

Here is where you can start from:

```
/([^,]\+,\s\(\w\+\)=.*)
```

Decomposing:

```
/(       start matching a (
[^,]\+   match multiple characters that are not ,
,\s      match a , and a space
\(       start a matching group
\w\+     match word characters
\)       end the matching group
=.*)      match an = and anything until the closing )
```

This needs improvements but gives you an overview of how you can do it.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to @Nobe4 answer you could do the following:

- Create the file `~/.vim/after/syntax/python.vim`
- Put theses line in the file:

  ```
  syntax match PythonArg /(.*\,\s*\zs\w\+\ze\s*=.*)/
  hi PythonArg guibg=blue
  ```
- Adapt the second one with your prefered values.

This will create a syntax file which will add a syntax match for your arguments followed by a `=` and set the style to use. This topic [`:h mysyntaxfile-add`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#mysyntaxfile-add) should be interesting for you.

Also I used a different regex than the other answer, here is the detail (I don't know which one works better so you'll probably have to try):

```
(      Begin the pattern with a bracket
.*,    Look for any number of any character before a ,
\s*    Zero or more white spaces after the ,
\zs    Start the matching group (what will be highlighted)
\w\+   Match one or more word characters
\ze    End the matching group
\s*    Zero or more white spaces between your argument and the = sign
=      A literal = sign after your argument
.*)    Any number of any characters between your = sign and the closing bracket
```

Comment: Thanks for you help. I didn't know that I can add my custom syntax without modifying existing rules. Your pattern doesn't match keyword argument if it's a first argument in function. I'll try to fix that myself (I'm learning regexps right now to do that). As soon as I will learn how to do that I will post a comment.

Comment: I'm trying this regexp via vim search and I think that it matches only one keyword in function call. I need it to match all of them'

Comment: @user1685095: Yep you're right my pattern isn't good. I'll try to improve it and edit my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The as-of-writing [accepted answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/6732/9182) broke highlighting for strings inside function argument lists for me (by what alchemy I do not know), so here's a hopefully more safe version, based on [Statox' one](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/6760/9182).

```
syntax match PythonArg "\v[\(\,]\s{-}\zs\w+\ze\s{-}\=(\=)@!"
hi PythonArg ctermfg = 214 guifg = #ffaf00
```

`ctermfg` is for console terminal, `guifg` is for gui. Of course you're free to change the colors to whatever you find fancy. [Here's a handy list](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Xterm256_color_names_for_console_Vim).

As always, you do best putting this inside `~/.vim/after/syntax/python.vim`

For a regex breakdown, here you go:

```
\v      set to very magic mode
[\(\,]  capture either a ( or a ,
\s{-}   capture whitespace, nongreedy
\zs     start of the match (what to actually highlight)
\w+     one or more alphanumeric character, underscore included
\ze     stop matching; anything after this is delimiting only
\s{-}   once again, capture whitespace.
\=      one single equal sign
(\=)@!  ...not followed by another equal sign
```

The final check stops the highlighting from coloring conditionals. You can remove if it you want.

Comment: Sorry, you're to late. I've maid syntax file for myself.

Comment: That's fine; if someone else runs into the same issue I did they can take a peek here hopefully.

Answer (score 3):

I found that [@Wolfie's answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/9917) captures unwrapping of a tuple as a keyword and it also had trouble capturing linebroken keyword arguments.

Inspired by his regex I came up with the following to put in my `python.vim` syntax file. (Bear in mind that I'm originally using the `python.vim` syntax file from [sheerun/vim-polyglot](https://github.com/sheerun/vim-polyglot/blob/3ddca5da461ebfaa82104f82e3cbf19d1c326ade/syntax/python.vim))

```
syn match pythonFunctionKeyword "\v\s{-}\zs\w+\ze\=(\=)@!(\_s)@!" display
syn cluster pythonExpression add=pythonFunctionKeyword
syn region pythonFunctionKwargs start=+(+ end=+)+ contains=@pythonExpression
```

And the regex breakdown is very similar to [@Wolfie's answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/9917):

```
\v      set to very magic mode
\s{-}   capture whitespace, nongreedy
\zs     start of the match (what to actually highlight)
\w+     one or more alphanumeric character, underscore included
\ze     stop matching; anything after this is delimiting only
\=      one single equal sign
(\=)@!  ...not followed by another equal sign
(\_s)@! ...not followed by any whitespace or newline character
```

Note that this will not color a keyword argument written as: `key = value`. Which I consider a good thing, as that goes against the [official PEP-8 whitespace recommendation for keyword arguments](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#other-recommendations).