# How to change the color used to highlight function calls?

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I would like to know if it was possible to change the color used to display function name.

Let's take the following example (using Python):

```
def function1(arg):
    function2(arg)
    # ...
```

`function1` has a custom color, while `function2` keeps the default text-color. I would like to change its color to something else (or, by the one used to highlight `function1`).

Is it possible to change the color function names when they're called? I wasn't able to find any lead on that…

Comment: Question is unclear. You want function2 to be highlighted in the same color of function1? By the way, you can create your own syntax region and give them a  color.

Comment: I clarified it a bit. I don't care whether the same color will be used.

Comment: So, what you want to do? Function2 in some other color? Is it only for function2 or any function with default color?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible due to the fact that you'll have to "record" every function definition and then create highlight group for them. Maybe have a look at https://github.com/vim-scripts/TagHighlight

Comment: My advice would be not to worry too much about it. If you have too many colours on the screen then you lose the benefit of having highlighted items standing out.

Comment: You can probably adapt what I did in http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/6963/205