# Highlight function's keyword and parameters

Tags: syntax-highlighting

Follow [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/6731/vim-syntax-pattern-to-highlight-python-keyword-argument?noredirect=1&lq=1) @muru point out how to highlight keyword in a function and function name but I want also highlight parameters, for example:

`abc = myFunc(Green, Orange=Green, Green, abcd(Orange=Green), Green)`
`Green`: it's highlighted `green`,
`Orange`: it's highlighted `Orange`.

Assume that we matched function name:

```
syn match pFun "XXXX" contains=pFun nextgroup=pVars 
syn region pVars start="(" end=")" contained contains=pKeyword,pParam transparent keepend
syn match pKeyword "\i*\ze\s*=[^=]" contained
syn match pParam "[^,]*" contained contais=XXXX
hi def link pKeyword something_green
hi def link pParam something_orange
```

As you can see problems, It overwirte pKeyword with pParam (`[^,]*` also match `\i*\ze\s*=[^=]`)

**My question is**: How to write pParam correctly to exclude pKeyword that give correct highlight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lemme try to analyze the syntax a little bit...

1. Everything inside `(` and `)` are `pVars`
2. `pKeyword` are a sequence of identifiers followed by `=` but not `==`
3. `pParam` are identifiers that are not `pKeyword` nor a function call

So... lemme get the `pVars`: `:syn match pVars /\v\(\zs.*\ze\)/ contains=pKeyword,pParam`

I tested with `:hi pVars ctermfg=1` so I can see if the `syn ...` is correct.  With `:syn region`, the last `Green` isn't highlighted.  I guess that is not good -- so I excluded the brackets using `\zs` and `\ze` instead of using `:syn region` (though we still got the inner brackets -- at least we saved the last Green).

By the way, as suggested by @Rastapopoulos using `/\v\(\zs.*\ze\)/` directly we can see the highlighted region without bothering with `:syn clear`.  After testing the `/regex`, we know the regex works and using `:hi pVars ctermfg=1` helps us deal with `contained` and `contains`...

Next, the `pKeyword`: `:syn match pKeyword /\i*\ze\s*=[^=]/ contained`.  Oh we see the keywords *not* highlighted anymore -- that means the regex is also working.

After that, the `pParam`: Let's start with `:hi pParam ctermfg=4` so we can see which are captured just by look at the blue chars. `:syn match pParam /\i*\(\i*(\)\@!/ contained`  We excluded functions calls by the logic of "a sequence of identifiers, which is not followed by a sequence of identifiers with an open bracket `(`".

Wait, this is also having the issue of overwriting the highlighting for keywords!  `pParam` needs to also exclude `pKeyword`!

In that case, we make use of priorities! `:help syn-priority`

Let's reopen our vim to avoid the colors that we used to debug.

Rearranging gives:

```
:syn match pVars /\v\(\zs.*\ze\)/ contains=pKeyword,pParam
:syn match pParam /\i*\(\i*(\)\@!/ contained
:syn match pKeyword /\i*\ze\s*=[^=]/ contained
```

Then apply the colors.  See if it works?

[image: Preview]

**TL;DR:**

Sample Text:

```
abc = myFunc(Green, Orange=abcd(Green, orange=ab(abc(e),g)), Green, abcd(Orange=Green), Green)
```

1. (Optional) Start Vim with `vim -Nu NONE` to avoid plugins conflicting just in case.  Do `:hi pVars ctermfg=7 | hi pParam ctermfg=4 | hi pKeyword ctermfg=1` to see highlighting in action.
2. Everything inside of () (excluding the outmost brackets) are `pVars` that contains `pKeyword` and `pParam`

   `:syn match pVars /\v\(\zs.*\ze\)/ contains=pKeyword,pParam`
3. `pParam` is a sequence of identifiers, contained in `pVars`, *not* immediately followed by function names (Identifiers followed by an open bracket, i.e. `\i*(`, note that `=` is not identifier by default: `:help /character-classes` `:help isident`)

   `:syn match pParam /\i*\(\i*(\)\@!/ contained`
4. `pKeyword` -- identifiers followed by a `=` but not `==`, overriding `pParam` (as `pParam` also catches keyword -- we can negative lookahead if we want though)

   `:syn match pKeyword /\i*\ze\s*=[^=]/ contained`
5. (Extra) If we want to highlight function names inside `pVars`, recall that in (2.) function names are identifiers followed by an open bracket:

   `:syn match pFunc /\i*\ze(/ containedin=pVars contained` and use `:hi pFunc ctermfg=6` to check.  However I haven't found a way to also highlight the outermost function call...

[image: highlight inner function calls]

Comment: I tried your syntax but it got cleared in my gvim8/windows, no clues. `for id in synstack(line("."), col(".")) | echo synIDattr(id, "name") | endfor` shows nothing. It should work as you did. I'll dig more when I have spare time. The question is: Does it work with nested function? Where to put match function name? I think your answer is closest.

Comment: Edited my answer! Please see if 0-4 works for you -- sorry that I haven't found a nice way to also include the outermost function calls in 5. ;)

Comment: It works well. What if we have newlines between parameters? That would be outermost `)` in seperated line, or maybe some inner `)`.